# Adding SSL on Google Cloud WordPress HA makes wp-admin inaccessible

Tags: wordpress, ssl, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-load-balancer

I'm Trying to implement the Google Cloud High Availability WordPress setup and its located here in marketplace https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/click-to-deploy-images/wordpress-ha and i was able to deploy successfully without any issues until the tried to enable the SSL.

I followed Standard Steps to deploy SSL using Google Certificate Engine on Load Balancer:

**Steps:**

1. Updated DNS on the domain
2. I followed this guide https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/google-managed-certs
3. Then I was able to see that SSL is deployed
4. I updated the domain of the site using WP Dashboard

**Issues I am facing now:**

- When i tried to visit the site, the site wasn't loading the assets like images, css and js because it had mixed content issue.
- When I tried to visit the admin panel again, I wasn't able to get there and I kept seeing to many redirects issue there.

Comment: I have seen this problem. I do not remember the exact solution, but it was related to the Apache configuration. Post your Apache configuration files including the virtual hosts and  the `.htaccess` file if you are using one in your question.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have checked the server and it seems that Apache is using this configuration (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/click-to-deploy/blob/master/vm/chef/cookbooks/wordpress-ha/templates/wordpress.conf.erb)
<Directory /var/www/html>
  Options -Indexes
  AllowOverride FileInfo
</Directory>
And for .htaccess file, i wasn't able to find any in the directory but i created the .htacess with default configuration which is used. And still issue persisted.